# RegEx in SQL - How to Change the values of a column in SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I am trying to change the values of a column in my SQL Server Database.

Table: crm.activity

Column: Content

The values look like this:

```
value 1:
```

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2055{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 **Appointment made**\par
}

```
value 2:
```

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2055{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 **Ask for offer**\par
}

What I need is just the bold text.

Is it possible like using RegEx to go through all the columns and change the value???

Comment: Is this `{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2055{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}` and `\par }` is always the same?

Comment: "my SQL" database. Is it MySQL, or "your" SQL Server database?

Comment: The beginning is always the same except for changes in the Font ( sometimes araial but mostly sans serif) and there is always a **"fs + number"** before the text value and it ends with **"\par }"**

Comment: it's "my" SQL Server Database

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can't do regex replaces in MySQL out of the box. However, if there's only one bold string per column, it should be easy enough to do the trick with string functions like `LOCATE` and `SUBSTR`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Here you go. This is for MySQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2055{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}} \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 **Appointment made**\par}', '**', -2), '**', 1);
# => Appointment made
```

Or to update (try it first and make sure you have a backup):

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, '**', -2), '**', 1);
```

Comment: Yes, absolutely. But answer @bagonyi's question on your question first since the solution is much simpler if the answer is "yes, they are always the same".

Answer (score 0):

If its SQL Server, do a bit of googling (`mssql update replace regex`) on how to add a regex replace method to SQL server. The regex you will need is: `.+\\fs\d+\s(.+)\\par\s?}`, replace this with $1. As a fallback solution (not sure how much data you have in that table) you could write a small script that selects all records, replaces the string, and updates the database.